# mat-select value is not shown when values are numbers

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using mat-select like this

```
 <select formControlName="commision" [value]="commision" style="width: 37%"  disableRipple>
  <mat-option value="null" disabled selected>Select Commission</mat-option>
  <mat-option value=0.15>15%</mat-option>
  <mat-option value=0.2>20%</mat-option>
  <mat-option value=0.3>30%</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

and I wanted the selected value to be selected and shown, according to commission value
created in form `commision: [this.data.element.commision, Validators.required],`

But the value is not shown whatever I do, so do select doesn't take number as values? Or what can I do in order for it to work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- dont add [value]="commision" to the select this should be bound by the form control that you have specified
- mat-select needs to be in both opening and closing tag
- if you want to display the initial selected value add [value] to your mat-options ie. [value]=0.15
- Example
- [image: List item]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's because you're passing in the values incorrectly to mat-option. Instead of `value=0.15`, you should do `[value]=0.15` .

Also the use ngModel instead of `[value]`  in the mat-select. `<mat-select [(ngModel)]="commission">` 
EDIT: noticed you’re using formControlName instead so no need to use ngModel, you can just get rid of `[value]`

Comment: Im using [value]="1", fixing my mistake value="1", readgind de value as string. That alows me to get the control value as number, and preselecting in ngOnInit() default control form initialization.
Ty for the lights...